# Reading Image path from text file and add it to thumbnail control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I have a [`CheckedListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) and a thumbnail control and I am trying to save and retrieve back the images along with their path.

I need to show their image path in the checked list box which I am able to do but I am unable to get the images.

I want to know how to read Images from the saved text file and display it in the thumbnail control.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub LoadProject_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
                     ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoadProject.Click

    Using ofdlg As New Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog

        ofdlg.DefaultExt = "amk"
        ofdlg.Filter = "AquaMark Project|*.amk"
        ofdlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
        If ofdlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim r As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Test\test.txt")
            While (r.Peek() > -1)
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add((r.ReadLine), CheckState.Checked)
                Dim Pname As String
                For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                    Pname = CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString


                Next
            End While
            r.Close()


            Dim SaveData As New gCanvasData
            Using objStreamReader As New StreamReader(ofdlg.FileName)
                Dim x As New XmlSerializer(GetType(gCanvasData))
                SaveData = CType(x.Deserialize(objStreamReader), gCanvasData)
                objStreamReader.Close()
            End Using

            With SaveData
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.ZoomFactor = 1
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.ImageXYReset()
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.Image = .Image
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.gAnnotates = .gAnnotates
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.RebuildAll()
                frmDisplay.GCanvas1.AssembleBitmap()
            End With
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code and placing the code here so that it might help others:

```
   Dim sr1 As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Test\test.txt")
            While (sr1.Peek() > -1)
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add((sr1.ReadLine), CheckState.Checked)
                CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
            End While
            sr1.Close()

            Dim sr2 As New IO.StreamReader("C:\Test\test.txt")
            While (sr2.Peek() > -1)
                Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(sr2.ReadLine)
            End While
            sr2.Close()
```